# Asus PCE-N53 Driver Issues

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I'm simply attempting to get my Wi-Fi card working with the latest version of Ubuntu. (16.04.2) I've followed the instructions shown at (https://askubuntu.com/questions/851222/how-to-enable-wireless-card-asus-pce-n53-11n-n600-rt5592-using-ubuntu-16-04-lt) however this leads to an installation failure and I imagine it's simply due to changes in the newer versions of Ubuntu.

I've been searching across the internet but I cannot find anything concrete about how I might go about this; any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to be more specific. The link you sent, doesn't mention any steps(at least not an approved one). So i dig around a little and learned that GNU/Linux kernel does not recognizes this type of wireless card(Surprise!!! ASUS... Right -.-). So what you can try is that install the propriety driver for that wireless card. One link is supplied below. Second thing you can do is upgrade your computer to 16.10 version which may also help. Or third option sends us error messages, images, steps that you followed and results to us so that we can suggest more reliable solutions.

Visit https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/PCEN53/HelpDesk_Download/